# mvvm binding custom event in custom window with viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have the following scenario that I am hoping to find a resolution for, I have a custom `Window` class and I have created an event as below (i have remove some of the code for brevity)

```
public class AeroWindow : Window
{
    public delegate void SystemMenuEventHandler(object sender);
    public event SystemMenuEventHandler Exit;

    ...

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        ...
        var exitButton = this.GetTemplateChild("SM_ExitButton") as Button;
        if (exitButton != null)
        {
            exitButton.Click += (sender, args) => { this.OnExit(); };
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnExit()
    {
        if (this.Exit != null)
        {
            this.Exit(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using MVVM with Calibutn.Micro and i have a ShellViewModel and ShellView (the ShellView inherits from AeroWindow)

What I would like to know is the following:

- How should I correctly create custom events, is the above correct?
- How do i then bind to said "event" in the view model
- Can the same method of event be used to bubble the events from one view model to another (for example I have the ShellViewModel which initially loads a LoginViewMode (UserControl) and that in turn loads a MainViewModel (UserControl), if I have an event on the Window called `Exit` can the ShellViewModel subscribe to that and bubble it to the loaded view or should the loaded view subscribe to the window events)

I know that is a number of questions but they are all related to the same thing and I am hoping that someone can provide an answer.

Comment: Why would you like to bind the exit event to the viewmodel? Does the view model need to know that you are exiting the app?

Comment: exit was just an example, obviously the AeroWindow would handle exit, there will be other events I will want to create and bind

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer each of your questions

**How should I correctly create custom events, is the above correct?**

- *I think what you did above is correct or you can add an event handler like the usual.*
- *If you're talking about custom events where you will create your own event aside from the built in events of a class, you can actually do that just create a [delegate and an event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx) within your class.*

**How do i then bind to said "event" in the view model**

- *I don't think you want to bind events, what you want to do is to bind commands. You can try to read about ICommand, Relaycommand,
  DelegateCommand. You can create an ICommand property in your
  viewmodel then bind it to the Command property of the button. There
  are also some tools that allows you to bind to events, try to look
  for some libraries that offers EventToCommand*

**Can the same method of event be used to bubble the events from one view model to another (for example I have the ShellViewModel which initially loads a LoginViewMode (UserControl) and that in turn loads a MainViewModel (UserControl), if I have an event on the Window called Exit can the ShellViewModel subscribe to that and bubble it to the loaded view or should the loaded view subscribe to the window events)**

- *In this scenario, where two viewmodel is involved, since you're using caliburn.micro, you might want to check on the

  [EventAggregator](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator). This will allow you to publish an event from

  one viewmodel and subscribe on another viewmodel. Then once the

  publish is invoked, all the subscriber will be notified.*